# Trigger update button woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have a cron job that runs and add some products into the Wordpress DB as products.

But after adding these products I have to go to each products and press the update button. Then it becomes visible in my products page.

Do you know any function, hook, action which can I call in order to do this job for me?

Comment: Share the code you are having wrong post status due to that this issue is coming.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the parameter to your wp insert post function.

Add below line to your parameter or if you are having the below parameter than just change the value.

```
    'post_status' => 'publish'
```

Comment: I have created them in a same way you have mentioned but still they are not shown until I press that ugly blue update button in each product.

` $product = array(
                          'post_title'      => $productInformation['name'],
                          'post_status'  => 'publish',
                          'post_type'     => 'product',
            'post_excerpt'=>  $productInformation['description']
 );

 // Insert the post into the database
 $productID = wp_insert_post($product);`

Comment: update_post_meta($new_prod_id, '_visibility', 'visible'); try with this.

Comment: Check the link. https://lukasznowicki.info/insert-new-woocommerce-product-programmatically/

Comment: Does that link is helpful?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you could try [**`wc_delete_product_transients( $post_id );`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_delete_product_transients.html).

**`$post_id`** parameter is the product ID.

> This will delete/refresh/generate all the cached data for a defined product ID

Comment: that didn't solve it for me. The product data is displayed correctly in the backend and also the database reflects this data. But without the click on the update button in the backend the changes are not effective.
Does anyone have an explanation for this?